# Updatig URL and content with AJAX, and also making that link works without AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, navigation

I want to make my website have page navigation like Facebook does. I mean when click a link on Facebook from the navigation bar on the left side(News Feed, Pages, Lists etc.) only Facebook content flow, advertising side bar changes(in short, middle and right columns) and URL changes. No page redirection happens.

One thing also, I have learned that you can change URL with History API but, how is it possible to make when another person uses that link and you make them to get into that page? For instance, you have index.php and profile.php. In index.php you have navigation bar, and a few good basic items you never change. When you load profile.php into a on index.php with AJAX and change the URL to www.example.com/profile.php from www.example.com/index.php its ok.

However if someone else uses that link later, how i am going to merge index.php and profile.php? I dont have navigation bar in profile.php, I only have the AJAX info to use inside index.php.

SCREENSHOT: http://tinypic.com/r/idsjsh/8

I hope I explained everything clearly. I am really wondering how facebook achieves this.

Comment: I have a bar on left with a bunch of li's.  My jquey says on click fire Ajax call to load page in to my main body div.

Comment: Yeah I know that, and I can do that already, but what I see on Facebook is way more functional. It changes url, so you cdan visit that url and it gets you both navigation bar and ajax content. Moreover, they are making this via <a> tag.

Comment: I'll give you the same advice everyone gave me. Google is your best friend.

Comment: I have searched for this, but couldnt find and appropriate answer. People just saying change History API. yeah but then what? how do I know that a request to my profile.php script is a AJAX request or user just pasting the URL? So that I can send either full page or just AJAX content.